# Tomcat Hot Deploy not working

Tags: tomcat6, hotdeploy

I'm having an issue hot deploying a new WAR on my Tomcat 6 server.

When I add in my new WAR I can see that Tomcat is attempting to deploy it. However, I believe the problem lies in undeploying the old war - the exploded war folder's contents are all deleted - except the WEB-INF folder.

If I stop the server, delete the WEB-INF folder and then start again, my war is deployed correctly.

Can anyone suggest anything which may be happening here?

Thanks.

Comment: Debugging 101: verify your assumptions. Have you extracted the contents of your WAR file into a clean directory and verified that you're actually including the correct WEB-INF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution, the problem lies in the fact that Windows locks the folder when Tomcat is running. To remove this locking, just edit context.xml in the Catalina Home, change

```
<context>
```

to:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```