# Why Grails war file gets corrupted sometimes

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat6

We are using grails 1.3.4, we have 2 physical servers running separate load balanced tomcats. At times when I deploy war file on these tomcats one of the server starts giving strange errors, to fix I have to clean the ROOT context where war is exploded and restart tomcat again it works or starts giving some other error.

Currently I was getting this error and clearing context and restarting again fixed the issue

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.coollabs.cooldeals.Address.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Any clue whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you hot deploying the war? If so, it may be related to this: [Tomcat Hot Deploy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465422/tomcat-hot-deploy-not-working)

i.e., edit your context.xml and add either antiJARLocking=true or antiResourceLocking=true. The [Tomcat Docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) suggest against setting both to true:

> antiJARLocking is a subset of antiResourceLocking and therefore, to prevent duplicate work and possible issues, only one of these attributes should be set to true at any one time.

Comment: I'm not hot deploying, tomcat is shutdown, ROOT context is deleted new war is copied where the ROOT.xml is expecting it to be and then tomcat is started again.